# Irreducible components of Spec$(k[t] \otimes_{k[t^2]} k[t])$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This has already been asked in [Question about irreducible components of the fiber product $\operatorname{Spec}(k[t]) \times_{\text{Spec}(k[t^2])} \operatorname{Spec}(k[t])$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259223/question-about-irreducible-components-of-the-fiber-product-operatornamespec), but the answer there differs from mine and I don't know what I did wrong. My reasoning was that
$$ k[t] = k[t^2] \cdot 1 \oplus k[t^2] \cdot t $$
and therefore
$$ k[t] \otimes_{k[t^2]} k[t] \cong (k[t^2] \cdot 1 \otimes_{k[t^2]} k[t]) \oplus (k[t^2] \cdot t \otimes_{k[t^2]} k[t]) \cong k[t] \oplus k[t]. $$
This way the fibered product is the disjoint union of two lines. I also don't know where the hypothesis on the characteristic comes into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(for $char(k)\ne 2$)

$R=k[t] \otimes_{k[t^2]} k[t]\cong k[t,u]/(u^2-t^2)$. The two minimal prime ideals are $(t-u)$ and $(t+u)$.

The two affine lines $Spec(R/(t-u)),Spec(R/(t+u))$ are not disjoint, they are glued along the maximal ideal $(t,u)$.

$R\cong k[x,y]/(xy)$.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I saw and understood the answer from the other post. Therefore I see that my answer is wrong. The problem is that I don't see WHY my answer is wrong, i.e. which part of the reasoning fails.

Comment: Because you are thinking to $k[t^2]$ modules not rings ($k[t^2]$-algebras) and the module structure doesn't tell much about prime ideals